# Multiple applications and plugins for docker build?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, docker

So I am relatively new to Docker and I was wondering if there is a way with either docker-compose or cloud-cli to create a Java environment with different plugins and other software needed for an application?

For example, I would like to start with configuring *Eclipse*, *Java*, *Tomcat*, and *Maven* together as one environment natively. And if so could you explain and maybe show an example of how to do this? I am on a Windows 10 machine.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Look at [Vagrant](https://www.vagrantup.com/) to establish a VM. You may also be interested in looking at something like [Ansible](https://www.ansible.com/), although you may not require it here.

Answer (score 0):

You can totally do that using Docker-compose for java, tomcat and maven.
For eclipse it will be kinda problematic since it's a graphical application, but you still can do it using volumes.

You could also consider using Vagrant if it's for a development environment.